# How to allow non-roots to connect to WiFi?

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, wpa-supplicant

`/etc/os-release` says `Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)`

`/proc/version` says `Linux version 4.4.132+ (jenkins@fdc-06) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) ) #1 SMP`

`sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -v` prints `wpa_supplicant v2.4`

I’m setting thses permissions in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` config file.

Tried both ways, the [documented](https://linux.die.net/man/5/wpa_supplicant.conf) one:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=linaro
```

and another one I’ve found after reading source code of that supplicant:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=linaro
```

Neither of them works:

```
$ ls -la /var/run/wpa_supplicant
ls: cannot open directory '/var/run/wpa_supplicant': Permission denied
$ sudo ls -la /var/run/wpa_supplicant
srwxrwx---  1 root root   0 Mar 22 19:24 wlan0
```

Both owner and group is root despite what’s written in the config.

Worked OK just a few months ago, with Linux 4.4.71+.

How to set the permissions on that UNIX socket?

P.S. Some context: this is embedded system running on ARM SoC. I’m consuming that control interface programmatically, i.e. I need my software, running under normal user account, control Wi-Fi: connect, disconnect, set passwords, etc. There's no Linux desktop nor X-windows running.

**Update:** as advised in the comments, adding more context. This is custom made embedded device based on [RK3288](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockchip_RK3288), running Linux kernel, minimal set of systemd services (wpa_supplicant is among them), and a single application I’ve developed. Users interact with my app using a touchscreen, and through the network (but first they need to connect somehow). There’s no X window or Wayland, no desktop, no mouse or keyboard.

Comment: Can you add your user to a group to allow for the rights to read/write/execute the files you need them to?

Comment: @kemotep I’ve included the output of “ls -la” in my question. Only root has access to that socket. I don’t want to run my software as root, among other features it exposes a couple of network services, running as a root have huge consequences for security.

Comment: What I am saying is that you can create a group and give that group the rights it needs to access that file/directory/socket. Alternatively you can open up the permissions on that location to allow non-root users access. Going with group permissions is more secure. Additionally if it is safe, that user can be given `sudo` rights or permission to run only a select number of commands as root. There are a few ways we can do this, what would constitute an acceptable answer for this post?

Comment: @kemotep An acceptable answer would answer the question “how to change security of that socket”? It’s not a file, it’s a UNIX domain socket created by wpa_supplicant process, it’s only visible in the file system for the lifetime of the server process. Even if chmod/chown will work, the changes will only last until restart of that service.

Comment: Is it necessary to complete those functions via this Unix socket and not by giving your user the necessary permissions to start/stop/configure `wpa_supplicant`?

Comment: @kemotep My users don’t have a keyboard and they don’t know what Linux is. Without that socket I won’t get notifications about new networks (I use them to show an updating list on “connect to wifi” screen). I won’t be able to implement WPS, pushing a single button on the router is the best way ever to connect to WiFi.

Comment: You mentioned using a user account which is why I brought up that point. How is the user account interacting/controlling the device? How does it work now and what is the utlimate goal? I have never heard of controlling wifi in this manner. It will help others if they know the full picture. Please edit your post to include this additional context, thank you!

Comment: @kemotep Updated, hope it's better now

Comment: Is that ***really*** the output of ``sudo ls -la``?  The output of `ls -la` usually includes **`.`** and **`..`**.

Comment: @G-Man I’ve stripped out the dots for readability. Also timestamp from /proc/version.

Comment: Well, if you’re not going to show us **`.`** and **`..`**, then you should probably just do ```ls -l```. But, more importantly, since you’re having a permission problem opening the directory (when you’re not root), it can be useful to show us the ownership and mode bits (permissions) on the directory itself; i.e., **`.`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that wpa_supplicant did not load my config. Not sure it loaded any config at all, I was unable to find path to default config in documentation or source code. Here’s how to fix.

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service
```

Find the following line:

```
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
```

Change it to

```
ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Reboot Linux to apply changes.

Not sure whether previous OS version had that in `wpa_supplicant.service`, or previous wpa_supplicant used default config; flashing the previous OS to NAND just to check that is a bit complicated.

P.S. Here’s relevant portion of the command line help.

```
  -c = Configuration file
  -C = ctrl_interface parameter (only used if -c is not)
  -i = interface name
  -I = additional configuration file
  -d = increase debugging verbosity (-dd even more)
  -f = log output to debug file instead of stdout
  -g = global ctrl_interface
  -G = global ctrl_interface group
  -s = log output to syslog instead of stdout
  -O = override ctrl_interface parameter for new interfaces
  -q = decrease debugging verbosity (-qq even less)
  -u = enable DBus control interface
  -W = wait for a control interface monitor before starting
```

Comment: Better way to override the service here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the way to set the configuration of a non-root group associated with the UNIX socket of *wpa_supplicant* is pretty weird (and not documented). The following steps could be useful.

- Create a group (*linaro* in your case); I will anyway use "netdev" in my examples, which should already exist in most distributions (if not existing: `sudo groupadd netdev`);
- associate the user to that group (e.g., for the user "*my_user*": `sudo usermod -a -G netdev my_user`);
- check how *wpa_supplicant* is started (`ps -ef | grep wpa_supplicant`):

  - if the `-O` option is used, like `-O /run/wpa_supplicant`, change it to a string including *DIR* and *GROUP* attributes, assigning *GROUP* to *netdev*, like in `-O "DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev"`;
  - if `-O` and `-i` are not used, while `-s` is used, then you need to set the `-O` option like before; notice that any setting included in the *wpa_supplicant* configuration file (e.g., `-c` option) will not be used in this case; example of correct configuration: `/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O "DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev"`;
  - if `-O` is not used, while `-i` and `-c` are used, then you can set the *GROUP* attribute in the *wpa_supplicant* configuration file (e.g., specified with `-c` option); example: `ctrl_interface=DIR=/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev`.

You can use `/var/run` in place of `/run` in the above examples, as generally `/var/run` is a symbolic link of `/run`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `wpa_priv`

Start  `wpa_priv` as root (e.g., from system startup scripts) with the enabled interfaces configured on the command line:

```
wpa_priv -B -c /var/run/wpa_priv -P /var/run/wpa_priv.pid [driver:interface]

wpa_priv -B -c /var/run/wpa_priv -P /var/run/wpa_priv.pid nl80211:wlan0
```

Then, run `wpa_supplicant` as non-root with a user that is in the wpapriv group:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Check `wpa_priv` man-page:
https://www.linux.org/docs/man8/wpa_priv.html